# How to make yarn detect a change of dependency version on a linked dependency

Tags: yarnpkg

I have a project P that has a dependency to our in-house lib, say LIB, which has itself a dependency to jQuery and to another module that depends on jQuery.
The dependency graph looks like:

```
P
|- LIB
   |- jquery@1.11.3
   |- virtual-keyboard
      |- jquery@3.3.1
```

I have, as recommended and as we used to do with npm and bower, used `yarn link` in the library and `yarn link LIB` in the project.

I am realizing that `yarn list --pattern jquery` is giving me the following result **in project P**:

```
yarn list v1.3.2
├─ @types/jquery@3.3.0
├─ jquery-ui@1.12.1
├─ jquery.cookie@1.4.1
├─ jquery@1.11.3  <--------------- PROBLEMATIC DEPENDENCY
└─ virtual-keyboard@1.28.0
   └─ jquery@3.3.1
```

At the same time, the same command (`yarn list --pattern jquery`) is giving me the following result **in module LIB**:

```
yarn list v1.3.2
├─ @types/jquery@3.3.0
├─ jquery-ui@1.12.1
├─ jquery.cookie@1.4.1
└─ jquery@3.3.1
```

Despite the `link`-ing, yarn is still using the jQuery dependency specification (highlighted in a code-formatted block above) that is in the latest commit on GitHub. Pushing untested changes to GitHub seems to be a mandatory move in our case, but I don't feel like we're doing anything extraordinary by updating the version of a second-level dependency.

Is there a means to make yarn actually use the dependencies specified in the package.json file of LIB currently under development?